# how to get a ResultSet from an outside java class

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, vector

I have a `ResultSet` object

```
ResultSet theInfo = stmt.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
```

but I want to have a function that can be called from another java class

```
public Vector loadStuff(){
    try {
         while (theInfo.next()){
             aVector.addElement(new String(theInfo.getString("aColumn")));    // puts results into vectors
         }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return aVector;
}
```

I'm not entirely sure how to go about this. I want to some how call a void method that returns a populated vector. is this possible?

Comment: Pass the vector as an argument.

Comment: Why don't you use [DAO approach](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/data_access_object_pattern.htm)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a class Demo and it has method getVector follow the given approach.

```
class Demo {

public Vector getVector(ResultSet theInfo) {
    if(theInfo==null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("ResultSet is null");
    }
    Vector aVector = new Vector();
    try {
        while (theInfo.next()) {
            aVector.addElement(new String(theInfo.getString("aColumn"))); 
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return aVector;
}
```

}

Now call the getVector after the getting the ResultSet.

```
ResultSet theInfo = stmt.executeQuery(sqlQuery);

Demo demo =new Demo();

Vector vector=demo.getVetor(theInfo );
```